# WLSTException: Error cding to the MBean on line 4

Tags: python, connection, weblogic, wlst

I have written a wlst script to create multiple connection factories. Code is as below :

```
def createJMSConnFac(systemModuleName,ConnectionFactoryJNDIName,connectionFactoryName):
    cd('/JMSSystemResources/'+systemModuleName+'/JMSResource/'+systemModuleName)
    cmo.createConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryName)
    cd('/JMSSystemResources/'+systemModuleName+'/JMSResource/'+systemModuleName+'/ConnectionFactories/'+connectionFactoryName)
    cmo.setJNDIName(ConnectionFactoryJNDIName)
    print "Created a ConnectionFactory !!"
    cd('/JMSSystemResources/'+systemModuleName+'/JMSResource/'+systemModuleName+'/ConnectionFactories/'+connectionFactoryName+'/SecurityParams/'+connectionFactoryName)
    cmo.setAttachJMSXUserId(false)
    cd('/JMSSystemResources/'+systemModuleName+'/JMSResource/'+systemModuleName+'/ConnectionFactories/'+connectionFactoryName)
    cmo.setDefaultTargetingEnabled(true)
    print "Targeted the ConnectionFactory !!"
```

And the loop from which this method gets called is :

```
y=1
while(y <= int(total_conf)):
    print '----------- Connection Factory Creation ---------'
    print 'Total Conf :' +total_conf
    conf_name=configProps.get("conf_name"+ str(a) + "." +str(y))
    conf_jndi=configProps.get("conf_jndi"+ str(a) + "." +str(y))
    print 'Conf Name :' +conf_name
    print 'Conf JNDI :' +conf_jndi
    print 'Conf JMS Mod Name :'+jms_mod_name
    print a
    print y
    createJMSConnFac(jms_mod_name,conf_jndi,conf_name)
    y = y + 1
```

Interesting thing to note here is that : It creates connfac1 properly however as soon as it iterates for second time , it throws me an error saying :

`WLSTException: Error cding to the MBean on line 4`

The values of jms_mod_name , conf_jndi and conf_name are being printed properly in both the iterations.
Is there anything else that I may be missing here ? Request your help

Thanks ,
Bhavin

Comment: Can you post the whole traceback?

Comment: No stack trace available.
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/wls_domains/ionix_dl/SingleTouchIonix/wlstByExamples/IonixDL_JMSConfig.py", line 220, in ?
  File "/wls_domains/ionix_dl/SingleTouchIonix/wlstByExamples/IonixDL_JMSConfig.py", line 97, in createJMSConnFac
  File "<iostream>", line 182, in cd
  File "<iostream>", line 1848, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error cding to the MBean

Comment: Any one to help please ?

Comment: Show the print out and the exception by `edit`ing your question. It will make it much easier to read than a comment. The edit link it right below your question. You don't show what variable `a` is, or `jms_mod_name`... one of them is likely the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create 3(or more) CFs with this code :

```
def createJMSConnFac(systemModuleName,ConnectionFactoryJNDIName,connectionFactoryName):
    cmo=cd('/JMSSystemResources/'+systemModuleName+'/JMSResource/'+systemModuleName)
    cmo.createConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryName)
    cmo=cd('/JMSSystemResources/'+systemModuleName+'/JMSResource/'+systemModuleName+'/ConnectionFactories/'+connectionFactoryName)
    cmo.setJNDIName(ConnectionFactoryJNDIName)
    print "Created a ConnectionFactory !!"
    cmo=cd('/JMSSystemResources/'+systemModuleName+'/JMSResource/'+systemModuleName+'/ConnectionFactories/'+connectionFactoryName+'/SecurityParams/'+connectionFactoryName)
    cmo.setAttachJMSXUserId(false)
    cmo=cd('/JMSSystemResources/'+systemModuleName+'/JMSResource/'+systemModuleName+'/ConnectionFactories/'+connectionFactoryName)
    cmo.setDefaultTargetingEnabled(true)
    print "Targeted the ConnectionFactory !!"

connect("weblogic","password","t3://host:port")
edit()
startEdit()
y=1
while(y <= 3):
    print '----------- Connection Factory Creation ---------'
    conf_name="conf_name." +str(y)
    conf_jndi="conf_jndi." +str(y)
    print 'Conf Name :' +conf_name
    print 'Conf JNDI :' +conf_jndi
    #print a
    print y
    createJMSConnFac('testModule',conf_jndi,conf_name)
    y = y + 1
save()
activate(block="true")
disconnect()
```

Comment: Thanks Kshitij for your help on this. I debugged to find that , value to this param : systemModuleName wasn't being passed correctly. Thanks